# How to specify output .apk file path when using fastlane gradle?

Tags: fastlane

I have different product flavors of my app and I build them with fastlane. This is my fastfile:

```
default_platform(:android)

platform :android do

  desc "Release apk with different urls"
  lane :release do
    gradle(
      task: "assemble",
      build_type: "release",
      flavor: "flavorname",
      print_command: true,
      properties: {
        "android.injected.signing.store.file" => "Key.jks",
        "android.injected.signing.store.password" => "KeyPass",
        "android.injected.signing.key.alias" => "KeyAlias",
        "android.injected.signing.key.password" => "KeyPass"
      }
    )

  end

end
```

The problem is apk files are created in project directory.

(projectname/app/build/outputs/apk/flavorname/release/app-flavorname-release.apk)

How to move this apk files to my Desktop automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't seem that `gradle` has an option to specify the output. 
What I suggest you is to add a command line just after the gradle is done to move this `.apk` to the Desktop or wherever you want.

```
sh "mv ../app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk path/to/Desktop"
```

Comment: Note that you can also get the path of the generated APK automatically with the environment variable / shared value `GRADLE_APK_OUTPUT_PATH`. Then you don't even have to hardcode the apk path (and filename).

Answer (score 12):

I use the following under my **gradle** call:

```
lane :release do        
    gradle(...)

    APK_LOCATION = "#{lane_context[SharedValues::GRADLE_APK_OUTPUT_PATH]}"        
    sh("mv #{APK_LOCATION} ~/Desktop/")
end
```

The advantage of using the variable is that you will be able to use the same code for release and debug apk.

Cheers.

Comment: For me the GRADLE_ALL_APK_OUTPUT_PATHS is always empty

Answer (score 3):

You can also use fastlane action [copy_artifacts](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/copy_artifacts/) instead of `mv`

```rb
lane :release do
  gradle(...)

  copy_artifacts(
    artifacts: ['*/build/outputs/apk/**/*.apk'],
    target_path: '~/Desktop/'
  )
end
```

Wilcard `*/build/outputs/apk/**/*.apk` will work with any build types, flavors app module name.

Or as said @janpio above, you can use variable `GRADLE_APK_OUTPUT_PATH`:

```rb
lane :release do
  gradle(...)

  copy_artifacts(
    artifacts: [lane_context[SharedValues::GRADLE_APK_OUTPUT_PATH]],
    target_path: '~/Desktop/'
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add like **archivesBaseName** in properties. And output is **app-release.apk**

```
lane :release do
      build_android_app(
        task: "assemble",
        build_type: "Release",
        print_command: false,
        properties: {
          "android.injected.signing.store.file" => "Key.jks",
        "android.injected.signing.store.password" => "KeyPass",
        "android.injected.signing.key.alias" => "KeyAlias",
        "android.injected.signing.key.password" => "KeyPass",
         "archivesBaseName" => "app",

        }
      )
```